# Pytorch and Torchvision are compiled different CUDA versions

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

```
RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=10.2 and torchvision has CUDA Version=10.1. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.
```

I am trying to run YOLACT on my Google Colab and found this error. Can someone help solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your `torchvision` to one compiled with CUDA 10.2:

```
pip install --upgrade torchvision>=0.6.0
```

or, if you're using Conda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Check [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision#installation) the version you should install based on your PyTorch.